# Devexpress Tiles' content display issue

Tags: devexpress, tiles

I have a user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UserInterface;component/Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <converters:WidgetWidthConverter x:Key="widgetWidthConverter" />
        <converters:TileSizeConverter x:Key="tileSizeConverter" />
        <converters:ListCountToVisibilityConverter x:Key="listCountToVisibilityConverter" />
        <views:SubplantMainStaticControl x:Key="subplantMainStaticControl" />
        <views:SubplantMainActualControl x:Key="subplantMainActualControl" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<dxlc:TileLayoutControl Background="{x:Null}"
                        x:Name="tileControl"
                        Margin="10"
                        Padding="0"
                        ScrollBars="None"
                        LayoutUpdated="OnTileControlUpdated">

    <dxlc:Tile Style="{StaticResource customizedTileStyle}"
               Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource subplantMainStaticControl}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource tileSizeConverter}}"
               Name="staticDataTile"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <custom:Widget Name="staticDataWidget"
                       DataContext="{Binding Path=StaticViewModel}"
                       CanResize="False">
            <custom:Widget.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewResources}, Path=Resource.StaticDataText}"
                               Style="{StaticResource widgetHeaderTextBlock}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </custom:Widget.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource subplantMainStaticControl}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </custom:Widget>
    </dxlc:Tile>

    <dxlc:Tile Style="{StaticResource customizedTileStyle}"
               Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource subplantMainActualControl}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource tileSizeConverter}}"
               Name="actualDataTile"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <custom:Widget Name="actualDataWidget"
                       DataContext="{Binding Path=ActualViewModel}"
                       CanResize="False">
            <custom:Widget.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewResources}, Path=Resource.LatestDataText}"
                               Style="{StaticResource widgetHeaderTextBlock}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </custom:Widget.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource subplantMainActualControl}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </custom:Widget>
    </dxlc:Tile>
</dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
```

where the views:SubplantMainActualControl is :

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserInterface.Views.SubplantMainActualControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
         dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Seven"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:UserInterface.Views">

    <views:LayoutLabelValueControl Grid.Row="0"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActualRepresentations}" />

</UserControl>
```

and the widget is :

```
<dxlc:GroupBox x:Class="CustomControls.Widget"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
           xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
           xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
           xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
           xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:CustomControls"
           xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Converters"
           xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:Business.Constants;assembly=Business"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           x:Name="baseTile"
           dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Seven"
           Margin="0,2,0,2"
           IsManipulationEnabled="True"
           Foreground="Black"
           Padding="1"
           Background="Transparent"
           MinimizeElementVisibility="Visible"
           Style="{DynamicResource GroupBoxStyle1}"
           VisualTextHintingMode="Animated"
           PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
<dxlc:GroupBox.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomControls;component/Themes/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter" />

        <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle1"
               TargetType="{x:Type dxlc:GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.BasedOn>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxlc:GroupBox}">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
                            Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="MinimizationDirection"
                            Value="Vertical" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding"
                            Value="11" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dxlc:GroupBox}">
                                <dx:Container x:Name="container">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalLayout" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MinimizedLayout">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="TitleStretcher">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="300"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="SeparatorElement">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MaximizedLayout" />
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                    <ContentControl x:Name="widgetContet"
                                                    Template="{DynamicResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
                                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                dx:BorderExtensions.ClipChild="True"
                                                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                                Style="{DynamicResource contentBorderStyle}">
                                            <Grid x:Name="layoutGrid">
                                                <dxlc:LayoutControl ItemSpace="0"
                                                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                                                    Padding="0"
                                                                    ScrollBars="None">
                                                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="groupBoxHeaderLayoutGroup"
                                                                      Background="{TemplateBinding TitleBackground}"
                                                                      ItemSpace="0"
                                                                      Padding="2"
                                                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding TitleVisibility}">
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="TitleStretcher"
                                                                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                                   Width="0" />
                                                        <dx:DXContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                                               Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                                               IsTabStop="False"
                                                                               Margin="9,0"
                                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                            <dx:DXContentPresenter.Template>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dx:DXContentPresenter}">
                                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </dx:DXContentPresenter.Template>
                                                        </dx:DXContentPresenter>
                                                        <Button x:Name="ColumnsElement"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                Margin="2"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewResources}, Path=Resource.ColumnsText}"
                                                                Command="{Binding Path=ColumnsCommand, ElementName=baseTile, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                Visibility="{Binding Path=ColumnsButtonVisibility, ElementName=baseTile, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                Style="{DynamicResource HeaderButtonStyle}" />
                                                        <Button x:Name="SettingsElement"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewResources}, Path=Resource.SettingsText}"
                                                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                                Style="{DynamicResource SettingsButtonStyle}" >
                                                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                                                <ContextMenu HasDropShadow="True">
                                                                    <ContextMenu.Items>
                                                                        <!--<MenuItem Header="Setting 1"
                                                                          Command="{Binding Path=SettingsCommand, ElementName=baseTile, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                                                <MenuItem Header="Setting 2"
                                                                          Command="{Binding Path=SettingsCommand, ElementName=baseTile, Mode=TwoWay}" />-->
                                                                    </ContextMenu.Items>
                                                                </ContextMenu>
                                                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                                                        </Button>
                                                        <dxlc:GroupBoxButton x:Name="MinimizeElement"
                                                                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                             Kind="Maximize"
                                                                             Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                                             Visibility="{TemplateBinding MinimizeElementVisibility}"
                                                                             VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                        </dxlc:GroupBoxButton>
                                                        <dxlc:GroupBoxButton x:Name="MaximizeElement"
                                                                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                             Kind="Minimize"
                                                                             Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                                             Visibility="{TemplateBinding MaximizeElementVisibility}"
                                                                             VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                        </dxlc:GroupBoxButton>
                                                    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SeparatorElement"
                                                               Fill="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
                                                               Height="1"
                                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding TitleVisibility}" />

                                                    <!--HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"-->
                                                    <dx:DXContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                                           ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding CurrentContentTemplate}"
                                                                           Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                           IsTabStop="False"
                                                                           Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                           MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                                                                           MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">
                                                        <dx:DXContentPresenter.Template>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dx:DXContentPresenter}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </dx:DXContentPresenter.Template>
                                                    </dx:DXContentPresenter>
                                                </dxlc:LayoutControl>
                                                <custom:BusySpinner Visibility="{Binding Path=DataLoading, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                                                    Style="{StaticResource busySpinnerStyle}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>

                                    </ContentControl>
                                    <Control Template="{DynamicResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"
                                             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=baseTile}" />
                                </dx:Container>

                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.BasedOn>
        </Style>
        <!-- Designer Item Template-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate"
                         TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid x:Name="contextGrid"
                  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate"
                         TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Grid>
                <custom:ResizeThumb x:Name="resizeThumbBottom"
                                    Height="1"
                                    Cursor="SizeNS"
                                    Margin="3 0 3 -1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=CanResize, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    </custom:ResizeThumb>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </dxlc:GroupBox.Resources>
</dxlc:GroupBox>
```

Now, sometimes the tile called "actualDataTile" is displayed containing only the header of the widget (a.k.a group box) as if the height of the widget is 0. If i reload the control, the tile's content is displayed correctly.

Can you tell me anything that can lead me in the right direction?